# The audio service is not running - Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-services

Yesterday, everything was working fine but today, when I turn on my desktop it booted up without sound:

[image]

I've tried to turn it directly on from `Services`, but still no success:
[image]

No updates were been made, no changes...

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

1 - <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

2 - cmd + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (open as administrator)

3 - SC config Audiosrv start= auto + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

4 - REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Audiosrv" /V start /T REG_DWORD /D 2 /F + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[Font](https://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/o-servi%C3%A7o-de-%C3%A1udio-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-em/0b3ad907-bb12-4464-952b-169ed687b053)